# What is the difference between enzymes shallow render and instance method

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I do not understand how the following two lines are different

```
shallowRenderedComponent = shallow(<SomeComponent />)
shallowRenderedComponentInstance = shallowRenderedComponent.instance()
```

The enzyme docs are very vague and I could not find any comparison on the internet.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

`shallow` returns a wrapper object that has all of the methods [enzyme](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html) define's in its docs (e.g., `find`, `setProps`, etc)

The `instance` is directly accessing an instantiated object of your React component. That is, the methods available on the instance are those that you wrote for that class in your application code.

As an example, if your React component looks like the below, your `shallowRenderedComponentInstance` will give you access to `handleClick`

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () {
    console.log("I was clicked");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <pre>Hello, World!</pre>
    );
  }
}
```